# Mesos master resolve

Tags: mesos

I have 3 mesos master setup for a cluster with 3 different. But I have a silly question here, how a application can resolve which uri to access. Lets say I am just browsing the admin console, do I have to try all 3 ip:5050 to get the hit?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only ever one active (leading) Mesos Master in a [HA setup](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/high-availability/) you only need to access that one IP. There *seems* to be a second question intermingled with the Master-related one, which I think revolves around the general case of mapping Mesos tasks to `IP:PORT` combinations: for this, [Mesos-DNS](http://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/) is a useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to try just one Master endpoint. It will redirect to the "real" Master automatically after 5 seconds if you hit a non-leading Master.

Answer (score 0):

When using [Mesos-DNS](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-dns) and add that to your local systems DNS preferences you just can enter http://leader.mesos:5050/ in your browser for example to access the currently leading masters WebUI.